# I'am can't to recive data from form to server-side code. Site based on node.js

Tags: javascript, server, gulp

html code for form. Its simply name, second name, phone, mail, message(textarea teg*) with submitting button.

```
                        <form method="post" class="register-form" id="contact-form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="firstName" class="mb-1">First name <span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <input name="first-name" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" required placeholder="First name" aria-label="First name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                                    <label for="lastName" class="mb-1">Last name</label>
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <input name="last-name" type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last name" aria-label="Last name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="phone" class="mb-1">Phone <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" required placeholder="Phone" aria-label="Phone">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="email" class="mb-1">Email<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required placeholder="Email" aria-label="Email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <label for="yourMessage" class="mb-1">Message <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="yourMessage" required placeholder="How can we help you?" style="height: 120px"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Get in Touch</button>
                        </form>
```

js code for collect data from form.
I also tried to make 5 const for all my inputs, but its still not sent to the server.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
const form = document.querySelector('#contact-form');
const message = document.getElementById('yourMessage')
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
            //collecting <form> data
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            formData.append('message',message.value)

fetch('/contact', {
method: 'POST',
body: formData
}) 
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  })

});
            
</script>
```

server-side code based on gulpfile.js
I cant understand whats wrong.
I'm only guessing that the problem is in the bodyparser, but idk.

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("dist"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//nodemailer
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body.name;

  res.json({ message: "Form data received!", formData: formData });
  console.log(formData); //{undefined} but i need data like {name: ... , mail: ...}
```

Comment: Can you explain why exactly you make use of the `bodyParser.json()` middleware on your server if your JavaScript sends a request body that's not formatted as JSON?

Comment: Its was wrong, sorry. I removed this.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it. All whats i was need to do its:
`<form method="post"  action="/contact">`

And for server-side code its:

```
const urlencodedParser = express.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.post("/contact", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)})
```